# Error when using plt.contour: Input z must be a 2D array

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I get the error message "`Input z must be a 2D array`" whe using matplotlib's `plt.contour` function.

I've already tried with `meshgrid` but it does not work, I can't really find the issue. `E = np.zeros(2500)` is an array so I cant find what's wrong.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as rd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mkgrid2d import *

W1 = np.linspace(-1.0,3.0,num = 50)
W0 = np.linspace(-2.0,4.0,num = 50)

w11 = 1.00
w00=1.0

w = np.array([[w11],[w00]],dtype=float)

mew = 0
sigma = np.sqrt(2)


Npts=50;rd.seed(1)
x1=rd.rand(1,Npts)*10.-5.0 #Npts uniformemente distribuídos
r = np.random.normal(mew, sigma, 50)*2.-1.0#ruído gaussiano distribuído

X = np.vstack((x1,np.ones((1,x1.shape[1]))))
X = X.astype('float') #converter para float

N=Npts 

y = np.dot(w.T,X) + r
E= np.zeros(2500)
```

"E" will be the Z for Contour

```
count = 0
for i in range (len(W1)):
    for j in range (len (W0)):
        w1 = np.array([W1[i],W0[j]])
        yn = np.dot(w1.T,X)
        E[count] = (1./50)*(np.sum((y-yn)**2))
        count +=1

plt.figure()
CS = plt.contour(W1,W0,E)
plt.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10)
plt.title('Simplest default with labels')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message says, you need your `E` array to be **2D**, of shape `(50,50)`, not a 1D array of shape `(2500)`.

There's a couple of ways around this:

1. reshape your `E` after assigning it

   ```
   E = E.reshape(len(W1),len(W0))
   ```
2. create `E` with the correct shape in the first place, then use your `i` and `j` to index it

   ```
   E = np.zeros((len(W1),len(W0)))

   for i in range (len(W1)):
       for j in range (len (W0)):
           w1 = np.array([W1[i],W0[j]])
           yn = np.dot(w1.T,X)
           E[i][j] = (1./50)*(np.sum((y-yn)**2))
   ```